# How to split large MP3s into multiple smaller MP3s?

Tags: mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way to split mp3 files?](https://superuser.com/questions/5315/is-there-an-easy-way-to-split-mp3-files)

I want to listen to audiobooks/podcasts on my MP3 player, but my crap MP3 has no ability to fast forward through a soundtrack or to skip to a random section. When I listen to them I often have to listen to the same thing several times because of the inability to skip.

I'm looking for some software that can automatically split mp3's into maybe 2-minute mp3's. I've found software that will do it if I specify the exact places to split; but is there something that will do it automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: dupe? http://superuser.com/questions/5315/is-there-an-easy-way-to-split-mp3-files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**AudioBookCutter**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audiobook_Cutter_Free_Edition) is probably what you will like.
[**MP3DirectCut**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mp3DirectCut) is also good tool for windows.

Comment: MP3DirectCut rocks!

Comment: upvote for mp3directcut.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using Linux you can always use "split --bytes=1M --numeric-suffixes largefile.mp3 smallfile". However, you will have to append the .mp3 yourself unfortunately.