# free MP3 splitter

Tags: mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way to split mp3 files?](https://superuser.com/questions/5315/is-there-an-easy-way-to-split-mp3-files)

Are there free MP3 splitter tools for windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/5315/is-there-an-easy-way-to-split-mp3-files

Answer (score 5):

[Audacity](http://download.cnet.com/Audacity/3000-2170_4-10058117.html?tag=mncol) is an excellent free program for editing MP3 files.

Comment: +1 Audacity is a very high quality program; highly recommend!