# How to join/merge many mp3 files?

Tags: linux, bash

Searching Google on how to join/merge many mp3 files, it suggests that I should just `cat` them together.

That might "work", but clearly it is not the correct way to do it, as each header and set of IDv3 tags will also be concatenated.

Does a Linux program exist that can be scripted to join/merge many mp3?

Can mplayer/mencoder/ffmpeg do it?

Comment: `cat` helped me to join corrupted mp3 files.

Comment: [\[FFmpeg docs\] Concatenating media files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

This will concatenate two mp3 files, and the resulting metadata will be that of the first file:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:file1.mp3|file2.mp3" -acodec copy output.mp3
```

This is because, for ffmpeg, the whole "concat:" part is a single "input file", and its metadata will be of the first concatenated file. If you want to use metadata from the second file instead, you have to add it as a dummy input file and map its metadata to that of the output:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:file1.mp3|file2.mp3" -i file2.mp3 -acodec copy test.mp3 -map_metadata 0:1
```

If you want to construct your metadata from the two metadatas, you'll have to do it by hand. You can dump a file's metadata with

```
ffmpeg -i file1.mp3 -f ffmetadata file1.metadata
```

After dumping both metadatas and constructing new metadata, you can add it to the output file with `-metadata`, and you can disable metadata copying by setting a `-map_metadata` mapping from a negative input file number. This sets a name value and no other metadata:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:file1.mp3|file2.mp3" -acodec copy -metadata "title=Some Song" test.mp3 -map_metadata 0:-1
```

Comment: FYI this requires a certain version of ffmpeg. If it says file not found concat... try upgrading and running it again

Comment: Works fine in ffmpeg 0.10.4 in Gentoo. What are you using? Are you sure you haven't just mistyped the command?

Comment: Ambroz I was saying that I had an old version and had to upgrade, then it worked.

Comment: Typing this in a DOS box in XP doesn't work: "'file2.mp3\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". Is the command Linux-specific?

Comment: @OverTheRainbow the argument is supposed to be "concat:file1.mp3|file2.mp3", without the backslash. The backslash is an escape character to prevent the unix shell from treating | as a pipe. I've changed it to use double quotes instead.

Comment: It's worth noting the mp3s have to have the same formats - I had one mp3 at 16000hz and another at 44000hz - they merged without error, didnt play - it wasn't until I used mp3val to see the issues and I had to re-encode my source files - then they merged fine

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

Comment: Just wanted to clarify a few things for others: `-acodec` means that audio codec will be used and `copy` mean that there will only be muxing and demuxing, but not encoding/transcoding (i.e. very fast and no quality loss)

Comment: When several files have to be concatenated, as in the original question, the following snippet might come in handy to construct the string "file1.mp3|file2.mp3|file3.mp3"etc:
`s=""; for i in file*.mp3; do s="$s|$i"; done; echo ${s:1}`

Comment: It would be great if there was a GUI program where I can drag and drop multiple files (e.g. sorted chronologically for recordings recorded sequentially, and perhaps some files edited) and it will then output one file.

Comment: This is a good answer, however in almost every case, the resulting MP3 file has a short (sub-second) gap between where the files were joined. So if you're trying to merge MP3 tracks to create a seamless playback album / set / whatever, this doesn't work quite right.

Comment: I corroborate @Lizard's remark and get nasty artifacts at the join seam when played with `mplayer`.

Comment: @JamesRay I'm making a web app front end for ffmpeg - add your email at lazypodcaster.com if you're interested in getting on the beta

Comment: Does not work for me. I get the error: "Invalid audio stream. Exactly one MP3 audio stream is required."

Answer (score 38):

This will concatenate a folder full of MP3 into a single MP3 file:

1) Save a list of the MP3 files to concatenate, e.g.,

```
$ cat mylist.txt
file '/tmp/01.mp3'
file '/tmp/02.mp3'
file '/tmp/03.mp3'
file '/tmp/04.mp3'
file '/tmp/05.mp3'
file '/tmp/06.mp3'
file '/tmp/07.mp3'
```

2) Run the following command (`-safe 0` is [not required if mylist.txt uses relative paths instead](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)):

```
$ ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp3
```

Comment: This works great if you have a long list of short mp3 files! Thank you.

Comment: in one command this can be used as: `perl -E'say qq(file '\''$_'\'') for <*>' * > file.list && ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i file.list -c copy myBigFile.mp3` (execute this in the folder with the single files. this will cause an error about "file.list" file but thats no problem, it still works

Comment: Just another one liner I used to join all mp3's starting with `test`: `ls -1 test*.mp3 | awk '$0="file \""$0"\""' | sed "s/\"/'/g" | ffmpeg -f concat -protocol_whitelist file,pipe -safe 0 -i - -c copy concat_test.mp3` The `awk` and `sed` is used to get the files in each line surrounded with single quotes

Answer (score 15):

[Mp3Wrap](http://mp3wrap.sourceforge.net/) - Command-line utility that wraps multiple MP3 files into a single, playable MP3, without losing filenames or ID3 information, and without reencoding. Also supports archiving non-audio data such as playlists, info files, and cover images inside the MP3. These files can be unpacked later (using mp3splt, e.g.); ordinary MP3 decoders can play the entire audio stream as one long track.

Comment: Thanks for this recommendation.. much lighter/simpler solution then ffmpeg, since I was combining 100+ mp3's and wanted the option of splitting back to originals.

Comment: This no longer works property - try concatenating a few files and inspect the output file in `mp3val` - it will report sync errors. This means that it will not play after the first chunk in Chrome 64+ (see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=794782 and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=806601#c10)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Windows. No metadata preserved.

Answer (score 13):

zsh:

```
audio-join() ffmpeg -i "concat:${(j:|:)@[2,-1]}" -acodec copy $1

audio-join output.mp3 *.mp3
```

Comment: We expect answers to include explanations.  (Not all of the answers on this page are good examples.)

Comment: The first line appears to create bash function `audio-join` consisting of the remaining text on the line. The 2nd line invokes `audio-join` to join all MP3 files in the current working directory into one having the filename 'output.mp3'. BTW, `ffmpeg` generates output with nasty artifacts on my system.

Comment: For some audiobooks I had to join mp3 files in 100+ subdirectories so every audiobook only consisted of one audio file. Using the above answer, and a for loop, zsh combined them all using `audio-join() ffmpeg -i "concat:${(j:|:)@[2,-1]}" -acodec copy $1` and then `for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && audio-join output.mp3 *.mp3); done`

Very nice!

Answer (score 6):

Based on Miles Wolbe's answer, here is a one-liner that worked for me:

```
ls *.mp3 | \
    sed -e "s/\(.*\)/file '\1'/" | \
    ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist 'file,pipe' -f concat -i - -c copy output.mp3
```

Comment: add `-safe 0` if filenames contain Spaces.
Error:
Unsafe file name '100 Vortrag.mp3'
pipe:: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 4):

One liner based on Miles Wolbe's answer to join all `.mp3` sorted by name in current directory:

```bsh
ffmpeg \
-f concat \
-safe 0 \
-i <(find "$(pwd)" -iname '*.mp3' -printf "file '%p'\n" | sort) \
-c copy \
merged.mp3
```

The find command finds any `*.mp3` and prints it with `file` prepended to the path. `$(pwd)` makes `find` print the absolute path. Piping to `sort` sorts the files by name. `<()` is [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) which allows output of find to appear as contents of a file.

Comment: Note that this requires `find` version later than whatever macOS has (for a reason surprisingly difficult to glean, but which seems somehow related to `-printf`).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to concat all mp3 files of the current directory:

```
function join_by { local IFS="$1"; shift; echo "$*"; }
files=(*.mp3)
ffmpeg -i "concat:`join_by "|" $files`" -acodec copy output.mp3
```

Comment: I used ```ffmpeg -i "concat:`ls -1 *.mp3 | tr "\n" "|" | sed 's/.$//'`" -acodec copy output.mp3``` is an alternative and worked well for me in zsh on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

If you need scripting, you're probably better off using the ffmpeg solution.  However, if you ever just need an application to do stuff like that, you could try out [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).  It's open source and cross platform.  I haven't used it to join mp3s, but I've used it to crop sections out of an mp3 and fade them out at the end.  I'm be willing to bet you can join mp3s and cross-fade them into each other with it as well.

Comment: Audacity, as far as I know, works on the raw sound data, and concatenating mp3's with it will result in a degradation due to transcoding.

Answer (score 0):

couple windows scripts I created to do this (using ffmpeg)

direnhanced.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.mp3') do (
  echo file '%%f'
  )
endlocal
```

mergemp3s.bat

```
call direnhanced.bat > fileList.txt
set /p FILENAME=Output file name then hit ENTER to continue...
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i fileList.txt -c copy "%FILENAME%.mp3"
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a list of your MP3 files in a format that meets the requirement, such as:

```
file '01.mp3'
file '02.mp3'
file '03.mp3'
```

You can do so from the windows command prompt:
(Given the current directory is in the mp3 files folder)

> c:>(for %i in (*.mp3) do @echo file '%i') > mylist.txt