# How to join mp3 files with their ends overlapping

Tags: mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Join multiple MP3 files (lossless)](https://superuser.com/questions/202809/join-multiple-mp3-files-lossless)

I need to join hundreds of small mp3 files into one.

I know there are several mp3 cutters and joiner tools, what I need is their start/end points get mixed/overlapped. One should be able to specify time span in seconds, that will goes fade in / fade out / intermixed / overlapped over another.

I need to be able to do it in a batch.  Any solution must be free.

Comment: I don't think this question is remotely related to SO but nonetheless, you could use `cat foo.mp3 >> Merged_Song.mp3` in a bash script if you are working on Linux or `copy` using `+` on Windoze. This will however not give you any control on fade or time span. You could `cat` a blank mp3 of the amount you want after each song if you want a pause. I'm not sure how to implement fades. You might want to look at [Audacity's Batch Processing mode](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/Batch_Processing).

Comment: [Search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62618/what-is-the-best-way-to-merge-mp3-files) before you ask.

Comment: Well I've been trying various suggestions from you people, unable to find a way to overlap their ends. OK let me correct the words, I actually need to cross-fade the mp3 files along with joining them into one. Normal Joining is not a pain for me. I have even programmed my own tool to join mp3s, can't just cross fade them. Any suggestions?