# Split long mp3 into individual songs

Tags: audio, mp3

I have a long mp3 containing multiple songs (mixed together; there ISN'T any space between individual songs, they just "blend" together when one ends and the second starts).

Is there some software that I can use that would **automatically** split this mp3 into multiple mp3s, one per file?

I have done a similar thing for wave files a while back, which relied on detecting beats, and flagging regions where the beats changed for splitting. However, it was terribly hacky, which is why I'm trying to find a better solution.

As long as it works, I don't care about the OS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to split mp3 files?](http://superuser.com/questions/5315/is-there-an-easy-way-to-split-mp3-files)

Comment: If songs blend and there is no silence between them, there is no way to "automatically" split them, it has to be done manually.

Comment: @Moab: yes there is. You detect the beats and see where they differ. I have done a similar thing for wave files, but I'd rather find a more to professional solution if there is one; I'd rather not have to code this myself

Comment: @Moab: also, please don't vote to close/link to a question that has little to do with this one.

Comment: then you better re-word your question and title and include more info, because as it stands it is a duplicate.

Comment: @Moab: no it isn't, please re-read. "automatically split this mp3"

Comment: @Moab: and I just made the "automatic" bold :)

Comment: I don't know of any automatic methods, only audacity, which is manual (i know this does not answer the question though, hence the comment instead). But surely the file can't have so many songs the only practical method is automatic? EDIT: when you say they "blend together", what do you mean? do they overlap (i.e. crossfade)? if so, that's a whole layer or two of complexity

Comment: @SylvestertheCat: yes, crossfade; however, generally you can detect the beats, and then it's just a matter of splitting at the region where they're confused (i.e. crossfading). The file is about an hour or two long, ~30 songs, and I need this more than once, so I thought there'd be no harm in asking

Answer (score 0):

There is a package in Gentoo called [media-sound/poc](http://www.bl0rg.net/software/poc) that has a binary called [mp3cut(1)](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/mp3cut/). It has worked for me in the past. This package also has a [mp3cue(1)](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/mp3cue/263361/) which does what you ask for.

If you are looking for something that analyzes the sound and tries to make a guess on where to cut, then unfortunately I don't know any software that does this.