# Split long music file with help of playlist file

Tags: itunes, mp3, music

Is there a program that can split an mp3 (and/or other music file types) into **single songs**, using an itunes **playlist file** (and/or other music playlist files) to determine beginning and ending of a song, all by itself?

Is it possible that maybe iTunes itself can do it? I heard of a feature that can split songs, but is it possible to do it like I suggested above?

Comment: I know cuetools does this with a cue file, but I have no idea for format the itunes playlist file is

Comment: @JourneymanGeek

.cue-files are perfect. But cuetools seems like a whole bunch of different programs. What exactly do I need?

Comment: Let me post that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm running J. River media center, and the purchased version allows for the splitting and combining of songs. I don't know if the free version offers this mode, nor if it will do so based on your deterministic criteria. Check it out- if nothing else, it's a great Multimedia manager, and provides the most versatile feature-rich tool palette I've found anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Cuetools is a pretty efficient ripper, which happens to be great for converting a single file into many. You want to run cuetools.exe

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Thank you very much!
However, when I choose **lossy** (mp3), it says "Exception: Unsupported audio type [PATHTOFILE].mp3" ...

Comment: thats odd. the cue files and the mp3s are in the same folder, right?

Comment: Yes, they are. I changed the output folder though. But this shouldn't be a problem, am I right?

Comment: does the output folder exist?

Comment: no ... I assumed it would create one ... seriously?
EDIT: I just tried, **same error**!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, there's a more general MP3 splitting question already answered:
[Is there an easy way to split mp3 files?](https://superuser.com/questions/5315/is-there-an-easy-way-to-split-mp3-files)